# Why does mypy not catch error when typealias is used?

Tags: python, mypy, python-3.12

Consider the following code that mypy catches the fact the wrong type is used.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, TypeAlias

V = TypeVar("V")

class MyObj(Generic[V]):
    def foo(self, arg: tuple[V, V]) -> None:
        ...

mo = MyObj[int]()

mo.foo((3, 3.4))  # Argument 1 to "foo" of "MyObj" has incompatible type "tuple[int, float]"; expected "tuple[int, int]"  [arg-type]
```

Can someone explain to me why mypy doesn't catch the error here?  Is there some way to create a type alias in this fashion?

```py
T_hint: TypeAlias = tuple[V, V]

class MyObj(Generic[V]):
    def foo(self, arg: T_hint) -> None:
        ...

mo = MyObj[int]()

mo.foo((3, 3.4)). # mypy does not catch this
```

Is this a bug of mypy or is there a subtle nuance I'm missing?

Comment: You need to write `arg: T_hint[V]`. Writing `arg: T_hint` is effectively writing `arg: T_hint[Any]` i.e. `arg: tuple[Any, Any]`. Turn on [`--strict` typing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict) (or the narrow option [`--disallow-any-generics`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-disallow-any-generics)).

Comment: :mindblown_emoji: ohhhh!!!  Thank you!  That makes sense.

Comment: Wait, `TypeAlias`es can take generic arguments? That's amazing!